# 22.04 LTS booting 25s delay [ 25.710318] i2c_hid_acpi: probe of i2c-INT33D1:00 failed with error -61

Tags: boot, 22.04, acpi, usbhid, i2c

I'm tired of waiting so long for my Acer R3-471 laptop to start up because of this error that shows every time. Apparently from a little googling it's an issue with the touchpad but other than some sketchy (for me) kernel patches for diffferent hardware to try I thought to ask here first for some help clearing up this issue. The touchpad and touchscreen do function.

Acer R4-471 2-in-1 with touchscreen
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS all up to date.

These are the lines that show while the system boots up, showing the delay timing with a retry every 6 seconds x 4:

```
dmesg|grep i2c_hid_acpi

[    6.252062] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-INT33D1:00: failed to reset device.
[   12.396093] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-INT33D1:00: failed to reset device.
[   18.540092] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-INT33D1:00: failed to reset device.
[   24.684084] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-INT33D1:00: failed to reset device.
[   25.708078] i2c_hid_acpi i2c-INT33D1:00: can't add hid device: -61
[   25.710318] i2c_hid_acpi: probe of i2c-INT33D1:00 failed with error -61
```

I would appreciate any guidance towards diagnosing and curing this annoyance. Otherwise the laptop runs 22.04 very nicely!

Answer (score 0):

You could download and install a newer kernel (6.0.8 for example) from [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/).
Information on how to do that is found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).
You could also blacklist the `i2c_hid_acpi` kernel module.
Simply add module_blacklist=i2c_hid_acpi to your bootloader's kernel line:

- When the boot sequence begins, the GRUB main menu is displayed.
- Use the arrow keys to select the boot entry to edit, then type `e` to access the GRUB edit menu.
- Use the arrow keys to select the kernel line in this menu.
- Type `e` to add boot arguments to the line.
- Type any additional boot arguments that you want to specify.
- Press `Return` to save your changes and return to the previous menu.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 excellent suggestions. I plan to wipe and re-install Ubuntu LTS on the old laptop in question at some point, when focussed time for that is available hopefully soon. That's a good time to throw v6 kernels at the system before I've mucked it at all like I've almost certainly done to some point learning the ropes on it so far. But will try the blacklisting shoirtly for sure, at least to speed up boot time a lot. Using a 480GB SATA SSD and liking the no moving parts and speed advantages a lot. The Acer was on its second HDD as it was!